# TypeError: Cannot read property 'capacity' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, interface

Before using Interface, It was running smoothly. Then, I implemented Interface in my TS code and facing problem. I don't what am i missing.

created Interface and then applied using object of interface.

Html file

```html
<ion-content class="ion-padding">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label position="floating">Class Code</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="code"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label position="floating">Class Name</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label position="floating">Instructor Name</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="instructor"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label position="floating">Class Capacity</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="capacity"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label position="floating">Location</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="location"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <div>
    <p>
      <ion-button color="success" expand="block" (click)="btnSubmit()" size="small" [disabled]="!code || !name || !instructor || !capacity || !location ">Submit</ion-button>
    </p>
    <ion-button color="danger" expand="block" (click)="btnCancel()" size="small">Cancel</ion-button>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Ts file

```
export class AddcoursePage implements OnInit {
      private classData: ClassDescription;
      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
                  public firestore: AngularFirestore,
                  public toastCtrl: ToastController) {}


async btnSubmit() {
   this.classData.remaining = this.classData.capacity;
    const res =             
    this.firestore.collection('/class').doc(this.classData.code).set({
    Code: this.classData.code,
    Name: this.classData.name,
    Instructor: this.classData.instructor,
    Capacity: this.classData.capacity,
    Location: this.classData.location,
    Remaining: this.classData.remaining,
    Register: false
  })
```

I expect that Load data using Interface

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `this.classData` is `undefined` at the first line of `btnSubmit()`

There is no initialization the the `private classData: ClassDescription;`in your code. Hence the undefined exception.

Comment: So , how i am supposed to initialize it?

Comment: **I figured it out.**

`private classData = {} as ClassDescription; worked for me.
[(ngModel)]="classData.name" to all binding
[(ngModel)]="classData.location" `
and so on.